# How to fix Webpack 'You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type' when running inside a container?

Tags: docker, webpack, docker-compose, jsx, babel-loader

**Issue:**

The issue is that the moment we start Webpack in a docker container it's not able to find the 'babel-loader` to parse the jsx even though we install the node modules in the container.

**Context:**

I have a docker-compose setup where I have a set of containers including a website where I run Express that renders a React website.

In the current situation we run de docker-compose and run Webpack on our local develop machines and the build.js files get mapped into the container and nodemon restarts the server. *This works*.

Because sometimes freelancers/new teammembers join this project their local node/npm versions may result in errors when running on the local machine.

This is why we want to spin up a develop container where we run Webpack and map the build files back to the local machine and into the website container.

Note that I'm not trying to have a webpack-dev-server running, it should just listen for changes in src files and output the build files.

**Attempts:**

- Change the node version of the container
- Updated the node modules to the latest version
- Install webpack/babel globally in the container

**Dockerfile-dev**

```
###############################################################################
# Step 1 : Create a base image
#
FROM node:12.6 as base
WORKDIR /var/www

###############################################################################
# Step 2 : Create all files needed to run the app
#
FROM base as builder
ARG SSH_KEY

COPY ./ /var/www

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN echo "$SSH_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN ssh-keyscan gitlab.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts

# configure the npm env
RUN npm set progress=false
RUN npm i --no-optional

###############################################################################
# Step 3 : Final image to export
#
FROM base

# Copy files from the build step
COPY --from=builder /var/www/ /var/www

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

**Docker-compose entry**

```
  develop:
    build:
      context: './site'
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    image: 'boilerplate-develop'
    container_name: 'boilerplate-develop'
    env_file:
      - ./config/local/.env
    restart: 'unless-stopped'
    volumes:
      - ./site/src:/var/www/src
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const {resolve, loaders, plugins,} = require('./webpack/common.config')

const PROD = process.argv.indexOf(`-p`) > 0

const getModule = type => ({
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js|jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|www\/)/,
            use: {
                loader: `babel-loader`,
                options: {
                    babelrc: false,
                    configFile: false,
                    presets: [
                        [
                          '@babel/preset-env',
                          {
                            forceAllTransforms: PROD,
                            modules: false,
                            useBuiltIns: false,
                            debug: false,
                          },
                        ],
                        ['@babel/preset-react', { development: !PROD }],
                    ],
                    plugins: [
                        "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator",
                        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                        "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring",
                        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
                        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
                        ...(!PROD ? [] : ['@babel/transform-react-inline-elements']),
                        ...(!PROD ? [] : ['transform-react-remove-prop-types']),
                        [
                            "module-resolver",
                            {
                                "alias": {
                                    "_scrollPercentage": [
                                        "./src/components/vendor/react-scroll-percentage/react-scroll-percentage.esm.js"
                                    ],
                                    "_components": ["./src/components/components.js"],
                                    "_actionTypes": ["./src/redux/actionTypes.js"],
                                    "_routes": ["./src/components/views/routes.js"],
                                    "_utils": ["./src/utils/utils.js"],
                                    "_view": ["./src/components/views/View.jsx"]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            },
        },
        ...loaders[type],
    ],
})

const client = {
    entry: {
        "js/bundle": [`whatwg-fetch`, `core-js/features/promise`, `./src/client.jsx`,],
        "js/intro": `./src/intro.js`,
        serviceWorker: `./src/service-worker.js`,
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, `src`, `static`),
        filename: PROD ? `[name].[chunkhash].min.js` : `[name].js`,
    },
    resolve,
    module: getModule(`client`),
    plugins: plugins.client,
    stats: 'verbose'
}

const server = {
    target: `node`,
    node: {
        __dirname: false,
    },
    externals: [
        nodeExternals({
            modulesFromFile: true,
        }),
    ],
    entry: {
        js: `./src/server.js`,
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, `src/server/build`),
        filename: PROD ? `server.min.js` : `server.js`,
        libraryTarget: `commonjs2`,
    },
    resolve,
    module: getModule(`client`),
    plugins: plugins.server,
}

module.exports = [client, server,]
```

**Error:**

```
boilerplate-develop |     ERROR in ./src/client.jsx 37:4
boilerplate-develop |     Module parse failed: Unexpected token (37:4)
boilerplate-develop |     You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
boilerplate-develop |     |
boilerplate-develop |     | const Client = props => (
boilerplate-develop |     >     <Provider store={store}>
boilerplate-develop |     |         <Router history={history}>
boilerplate-develop |     |             <App {...props} history={history} />
boilerplate-develop |      @ multi whatwg-fetch core-js/features/promise ./src/client.jsx js/bundle[2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your volume is mapped to `www` and you are excluding `www` in the webpack loader that searches for `js` and `jsx` files.
Webpack executes the regex commands on the full file path not the relative path.

Try and remove `www` from the `exlude` property and try again.